# How to download audio from web page other then youtube from command line?

Tags: sound, downloads

How do I download an audio file on a website other then Youtube from command line within terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Download all music files off of a website using wget -

`wget -r -l1 -H -nd -A mp3 -e robots=off http://example/url`

This will download all files of the type specified after "-A" from a website. Here is a breakdown of the options:

-r turns on recursion and downloads all links on page

-l1 goes only one level of links into the page(this is really important when using -r)

-H spans domains meaning it will download links to sites that don't have the same domain

-nd means put all the downloads in the current directory instead of making all the directories in the path

-A mp3 filters to only download links that are mp3s(this can be a comma separated list of different file formats to search for multiple types)

-e robots=off just means to ignore the robots.txt file which stops programs like wget from crashing the site...

[Source](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12498/download-all-music-files-off-of-a-website-using-wget)